# Your PC/Device needs to be repaired: computer doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image]
I've had initially Windows 7, but then I used one of the Microsoft's ads and upgraded to Windows 10. Recently my computer turned off due to lack of charge and refused to turn on again. I've read that I need a recovery disk/USB to fix that, but I have none since initially I had Windows 7 installed.

Is there a way to fix it, leaving my files undamages?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to another computer, you may be able to create a recovery disk.  Or if you know someone who has a recovery disk/usb, you should be able to use that.

If you cannot come up with one, you can try booting to a live disk and copying off the files you need.  Then you can reinstall.

Please make backups in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool [Windows 10 Upgrade Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

To download and burn a bootable image to USB or DVD. This should enable you to repair your system.

If you have valuable files you can try the live disk that Xalorous suggested then reinstall Windows 7. Once you upgrade to Windows 10 you can go back to 7 then back to 10 later for free. Once your key is locked in your good.